# Speeding up Mahalanobis distance calculation

Tags: numpy, vectorization, mahalanobis

**Background:**

I am implementing a Sequential Backward Selection algorithm to select features from a dataset. The dataset in question is MNIST. I have 60000 vectors of length 784.

The algorithm requires me to leave out one feature, `fi` from the total of 784 and select the remaining 783 features, called `selection` in the below code. I then must compute the Mahalanobis of each vector to it's respect classes' mean. Once this iteration is completed, I leave out two features and then three and so on. Each of these iterations take 3 minutes.

I have to select 500 features so the above is repeated 500 times, so in total the Mahalanobis distance is computed `500 x 784 = 392,000` times. This requires me to compute the inverse of the covariance matrix. The inverse of this covariance matrix does not exist as it is singular so I am using numpy's Pseudo-Inverse.

**Problem**

As you can imagine the above is extremely slow. Computing the Pseudo-Inverse is a slowest process. I thought I could get away with precomputing the Pseudo-Inverse and then deleting the corresponding columns and rows that are associated with `fi`. However, as it turns out this Pseudo-Inverse matrix is not equal to the Pseudo-Inverse matrix computed directly from vectors where I delete `fi` already.

**What I've tried**

I have tried vectoring this to a large extent and processing stacks of arrays only to find that the factorized approach was slower. I have tried np.einsum, cdist and even numexpr. Nothing really helps.

This leads me to believe the best chance I have at speeding this up is somehow moving the covariance and Pseudo-Inverse calculation out of this loop. This is my current code:

```
def mahalanobis(self, data, lbls, selection):
    subset data[:,tuple(selection)]

    for n in range(10):
        class_rows = subset[np.where(y == n)]
        mean = np.mean(class_rows, axis = )
        pseudoInverse = pinv(covariance(class_rows))
        delta = C - u
        d[n] = np.mean(np.sum(((delta @ pseudoInverse) * delta), axis = -1))
    return np.mean(d)
```

**Question**

How can I speed this computation up? From the tests I've done in the past week, it seems the slowest part of this computation is the line `pseudoInverse = pinv(covariance(class_rows))`.

Comment: Are you aware of [`scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis.html)? Edit: nevermind, it's not faster than what you have.

Comment: Yes. It is rather limited as it can only accept 1D arrays.

Comment: In numpy 1.16, you can pass `hermitian = true` to `pinv`, which might speed things up

Comment: @Eric I installed 1.16 but passing that keyword arg. gave me an error. The docs also don't mention anything about a hermitian argument.

Comment: Whoops, that's not until 1.17, sorry. My answer does the equivalent of it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your code is essentially:

```py
def mahalanobis(delta, cov):
    ci = np.linalg.pinv(cov)
    return np.sum(((delta @ ci) * delta), axis=-1)
```

You can speed this up a little by:

- Using `svd` directly instead of `pinv`, and eliminating the conjugations that you're not using.
- Using `eigh` instead of `svd`, which exploits the symmetry of the covariance matrix

```py
def mahalanobis_eigh(delta, cov):
    s, u = np.linalg.eigh(cov)
    # note: missing filtering of small s, which you might want to consider adding - pinv already does this for you
    ci = u @ (1/s[...,None] * u.T)
    return np.sum(((delta @ ci) * delta), axis=-1)
```

It's worth noting that neither this function nor your function work correctly for complex values.